# How to change/convert all index in the list into integer number in the python language?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I'm still learning about python programming, I'm just curious in list, I have code like this :

```
def getdirt(endrange):
    dirt_down = []
    for i in range(0 , endrange, 70):
      dirt_down.append(i)

    return dirt_down

print(getdirt(420))
```

and this the ouput from that code :

```
[0, 70, 140, 210, 280, 350]
```

and now I have a problem, How to convert that list to integer number, just like :

```
0
70
140
210
280
350
```

how ?

Comment: `for x in lst: print(x)`

Comment: use save my life dude, god bless you